# getting an error when I try to import ibm_db driver in python

Tags: python-3.x, db2

Macbook Pro
Python 3.11

I successfully installed ibm-db 3.1.4 via pip but getting the following error when I try to import it in Python

> import ibm_db
>
> ImportError: dlopen(/Users/kurtjob/projects/python/dbcon/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ibm_db.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: ___cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length
> Referenced from: <855AE640-1BCF-3A61-A65E-58F5490BFF43> /Users/kurtjob/projects/python/dbcon/lib/python3.11/site-packages/clidriver/lib/libdb2.dylib
> Expected in:     <47CF44A7-69F5-3878-AD7F-9C572B4E4F8B> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib

Comment: https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues/835#issuecomment-1503772903 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem, and has a workaround.

It is wise to first check on the python ibm_db github [issues](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues) page for already closed tickets that mention your symptom. Stackoverflow is not the defect-support channel for python ibm_db.

Please follow the instructions mentioned in the [README](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb#readme) relating to Apple silicon, and also in the comments on this [link](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues/835#issuecomment-1503772903) relating to exact versions of gcc libraries that are required.